# 2Checkout API - how do I edit a recurring sale

Tags: 2checkout

I want to enable subscription service for my customers through 2checkout recurring billing. When my customers change their plan, I want to update their recurring sale amount to a different amount. How do I do that.

On 2checkout documentation I did not find much on how do I edit the an existing recurring subscription.

Answer (score 4):

In 2Checkout, unfortunately it is not possible to edit existing recurring sales at this time. Once a recurring sale has been completed, if you wanted to edit the amount, you would need to cancel the current sale, and ask your customer to purchase a new one, with the updated price.

Comment: guys, any update? have they started edit in recurring sales?

Comment: @sphinx - no, please follow their web site with product updates. Currently they still do not have this feature